# How to label an equation at the end of a line

Tags: labels

What is the easiest way to label an equation at the end of the line? I have encountered

\label{eq1}

for the first equation and so on. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `\label` is just for internal cross referencing it does not affect the printed page (it is best to avoid numbers in `\label`),  `equation`  environments get an equation number automatically.  Please show an example where that is not happening, and someone will help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so I have to add \begin{equation} and \end{equation} for the number to show up on the printed pageif I use \label ?

Comment: `equation` and `align` (from amsmath) make numbered equations, `\label` is for cross referencing add `\label{fermat}`   to an equation and somewhere use `\ref{fermat}` and `\ref` will generate the correct number. The internal name `fermat` is arbitrary. If you are not using `equation` how are you marking up equations now? You have given no clues about your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give an example here of equation numbering.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section{Something}

numbered equation
\begin{equation}
  1=1
\end{equation}

multiline equation alignment
\begin{align}
  x&=1+1\\
   &=2
\end{align}

\section{Another thing\label{zzz}}

numbered equation with \verb|\label|
\begin{equation}
  2=2 \label{twos}
\end{equation}

multiline equation alignment with \verb|\label|
\begin{align}
  x&=1+1 \label{abc}\\
   &=2
\end{align}

You see \verb|\label| has no affect on the printing but is an internal
identifier so we can refer to Section~\ref{zzz} and
equation~(\ref{twos}) or and have the correct number calculated.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't think I'm familiar enough with TeX yet to understand all of that :( What is meant by a package/usepackage?

Comment: @A-levelStudent maybe you should start from a basic tutorial such as https://www.learnlatex.org

Comment: I have statrted reading through it, thanks for the link :)